# Проблемы с шифрованием

Tags: c++, linux, криптография, openssl, aes

Есть две функции - шифрования и дешифрования с использованием AES из библиотеке openssl:

```
bytes_t aes_encrypt ( bytes_t& buff, int keylength ) {
    bytes_t aes_key(keylength / 8, 0);

    size_t sz_buff = buff.size();

    bytes_t iv_enc(AES_BLOCK_SIZE, 'q');

    const size_t encslength = ceil((float)sz_buff / AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    bytes_t enc_out(encslength * AES_BLOCK_SIZE, 0);

    AES_KEY enc_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(&aes_key[0], keylength, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(&buff[0], &enc_out[0], sz_buff, &enc_key, &iv_enc[0], AES_ENCRYPT);

    return enc_out;
}

bytes_t aes_decrypt ( bytes_t& buff, int keylength ) {
    bytes_t aes_key(keylength / 8, 0);

    size_t sz_buff = buff.size();

    bytes_t iv_dec(AES_BLOCK_SIZE, 'q');

    bytes_t dec_out(sz_buff, 0);

    AES_KEY dec_key;
    AES_set_decrypt_key(&aes_key[0], keylength, &dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(&buff[0], &dec_out[0], sz_buff, &dec_key, &iv_dec[0], AES_DECRYPT);

    return dec_out;
}
```

Суть в том, что на x64 Linux все работает нормально, шифрует, дешифрует.
Но при использовании x32 Linux, на каком то из этапов происходит сбой.
Например: для шифровки подаю 54 байта, добавляю '\0' (0) до 64. на выходе получаю 64 шифрованных байта. При дешифровании я получаю последние 16(из 64) байт не тех. т.е. с 1 до (64-16 = 48) тот самый набор байт, который я кидал в шифровании, но после идет что-то не понятное. Буду благодарен за комментарии.
p.s.:

```
typedef char byte_t
typedef std::vector<byte_t> bytes_t
```

Comment: Приведите пример, в котором воспроизводится проблема и который можно скомпилировать.

Comment: Я передаю туда содержимое документа JSON:
**{"ip":"192.168.0.111","port":"8000","password":"1973"}**
потом зашифрованное сохраняю в файл, считываю и дешифрую и тут уже проблемы.

Comment: Я скомпилировал такой код http://pastebin.com/iFWS6FKv под Linux x86 и все работает

Comment: Что за магия. Какую версию openssl вы используете? Пока единственное отличие я увидел, в 32 разрядной стоит openssl 1.0.1f, а на 64 - 1.0.1m.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: Что-то я в большом недоумении. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: sz_buff чему равен при шифровании и расшифровке?

Comment: при шифровании 54,
при дешифровании 64.

AES_cbc_encrypt(&buff[0], &enc_out[0], sz_buff, &enc_key, &iv_enc[0], AES_ENCRYPT);
Просто при шефривке он должен после 54 байта дешифровать в 0. но он мало того, он ещё и до этого 6 символов корежит.

Comment: Ну вот и проблема :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев стало ясно, что проблема - в длине данных в AES_cbc_encrypt. При шифровании шифруется 54 байта, расшифровывается - 64.

Размер блока AES - 16 байт, 54 % 16 = 6, то есть имеется неполный блок в конце сообщения. Необходимо дополнить сообщение, чтобы оно стало кратно размеру блока, например, нулями и указать при шифровании размер дополненного сообщения. То есть 64 байта.

Comment: Правда, я не понял как именно openSSL себя ведет если ему сказать что длина данных не кратна размеру блока. Возможно, кстати, что шифрование последних 6 байт и не производится вовсе...

Comment: Но он ведь пишет `Например: для шифровки подаю 54 байта, добавляю '\0' (0) до 64.`. А `sz_buff = buff.size();` то есть 64 байта. Иначе куда он пишет нули?

Comment: Я явно спросил чему равны sz_buff - говорит 54 и 64. И поведение программы вполне соответствует неверным данным в последнем блоке.

Comment: Я не правильно понял как работает AES_cbc_encrypt, думал там в sz_buff  мы указываем размер поданного буфера и он сам скопирует во второй внутри, а там уже все в 0.
Забавнее всего, что этот код уже год работал нормально на x64 :DD
Низкий поклон, исправил, работает :)

Comment: Всегда говорил и говорить буду: держитесь подальше от криптографии, хлебнете с ней горя! :-)

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, Согласен! Долой HTTPS! Даешь plaintext!

Comment: Да я про другое... Такие вот "непонятные" проблемы, косяки в библиотеках, сложность тестирования...

Comment: В 99% случаев "непонятные проблемы" - это ошибка в своем коде и невнимательное чтение документации. Как и в данном случае.
Очень наивно надеяться на ошибку в детском примере в библиотеке, которая покрыта сотнями тестов используется в тысячах приложений.